How to convert a 'string' containing illegal characters to type 'mpz_t'?
I've written a code that partly needs to convert a number of type "string" to type "mpz_t" in order to perform a decryption operation. The data of type "srting" is ciphertext, so it is an illegal character. It seems that the conversion of "mpz" can't convert illegal characters (this may be because my computer doesn't use normal ASCII code, but with extension, but I can't change the encoding, so we still need to think of other solutions), the result of the conversion will only be The result will only be "0", so I'm wondering what I can do about that.
The part of the code I wrote is below:
// Decryption section
for (auto& str : decompressedData/*vector<string>*/) {

    // How to convert "str" to "mpz_t" in "void decrypt(mpz_t m, mpz_t c, mpz_t n, mpz_t d)"?

    // Update the decrypted data into the original string
    char* buffer = mpz_get_str(nullptr, 10, decryptedData);
    if (buffer == nullptr) {
        // Error handling
        std::cerr << "Failed to convert decryptedData to string." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        str = buffer;
        free(buffer); // Free memory
    }

    // Free memory
    mpz_clear(number);
}

After executing the following code:
mpz_t number; 
mpz_init(number);

 // Convert the string to 
mpz_t mpz_set_str(number, str.c_str(), 16); 
cout << "number:" << number 
  << "\nstr:" << str 
  << "\nstr.c_str():" << str.c_str() 
  << endl; 

Program output
number:0
str:***** (garbled)
str.c_str():***** (same garbled code as above).
If you use the constructor of mpz_t directly
For example, if I use "mpz_t (str)", sometimes I get an error, sometimes it's zero.

You can store bytes with value zero in std::string without problems. Only when treating it as a C string (i.e. a pointer to NUL-terminated string, like e.g. using the c_str() method) you will find that things don't work reliably any more. Also, if you just store bytes, you can't use that as base for output as text, it will just be "garbled", as you noticed yourself.

BTW: You're not even asking a question. I suggest you start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Then, extract a [mcve] and include that along with both expected and actual output.

How way the data transferred?  Did data get downloaded using HTTP?  What was the content-type?  You are assuming the data is decompressed (probably GZIP).  Without seeing the code that transmitted the data it is hard to determine what is causing the issue.
